# LWC: Inside an HTML template for-loop, set loop variable property to new user-typed input element value?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, javascript-controller, template

I'm trying to write a Lightning Web Component *(yay, first one)*.

Still in the "proof of concept; can I get user input to propagate around the page?" stage.

I have a `List<MyApexWrapperClass>` whose records I'd like to serve as rows of an HTML table *(and whose `@AuraEnabled` properties such as `value_for_freeform_column` I'd like to have serve as the columnar cell values)*.

I got the `List<MyApexWrapperClass` into a JavaScript controller `helloworld.js` property `wrapped_records` as follows just fine:

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import lwcMagic from '@salesforce/apex/MyWrapperFetcher.lwcMagic';

export default class helloworld extends LightningElement {
    @track wrapped_records;

    doMagic() {
        lwcMagic()
            .then(result => {
                this.wrapped_records = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.wrapped_records = undefined;
            });
    }

}
```

I'm working with a situation where I've got `@AuraEnabled` properties of an Apex class serving as the basis of a JavaScript controller variable I called `wrapped_records` *(note that that's plural -- I'm fetching from an Apex method that returns a `List<MyWrapperClass>`)*.
Then between `<tbody>...</tbody>` tags I have a `<template for:each={wrapped_records} for:item="w_record">` tagset where there's a `<tr key={w_record.unique_name}>` within, and `td`'s within those.
In the `td`'s, I am trying to do something along the following lines:

```html
<lightning-input 
  type="text" 
  label="Need to enter a manual value?" 
  variant="label-hidden"
  value={w_record.value_for_freeform_column}
  placeholder="type here..."
>
</lightning-input>
You entered:  <em>{w_record.value_for_freeform_column}</em>
```

The full HTML template `helloworld.html` is as follows:

```html
<template>
    <template if:false={wrapped_records}>
        <lightning-button
            label="Do The Magic"
            onclick={doMagic}
        ></lightning-button>
    </template>
    <template if:true={wrapped_records}>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-border_left slds-border_right">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Unique Name">Unique Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Freeform">Freeform</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template for:each={wrapped_records} for:item="w_record">
                    <tr key={w_record.unique_name}>
                        <th data-label="UniqueName" scope="row" key={w_record.unique_name}>
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={w_record.unique_name}><b><u>{w_record.unique_name}</u></b></div>
                        </th>
                        <td data-label="Freeform" title={w_record.unique_name} key={w_record.unique_name}>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">
                                <lightning-input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    label="Need to enter a manual value?" 
                                    variant="label-hidden"
                                    value={w_record.value_for_freeform_column}
                                    placeholder="type here..."
                                >
                                </lightning-input>
                                You entered:  <em>{w_record.value_for_freeform_column}</em>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </template>
    <template if:true={error}>
        There was an error.
    </template>
</template>
```

So far, my resulting table looks like this:

```
| Unique Name | Freeform                                       |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| ABC         | (Editable input box displaying "Hello World!") |
|             | You entered: Hello World!                      |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| JKL         | (Editable input box displaying "Hello World!") |
|             | You entered: Hello World!                      |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| XYZ         | (Editable input box displaying "Hello World!") |
|             | You entered: Hello World!                      |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
```

*(Note:  a `MyApexWrapperClass` object always instantiates with a `value_for_freeform_column` value of `Hello World!`)*

---

What I'd like to be able to do is backspace out the "Hello World!" in row "JKL" and type "Goodbye," and as I type, the "You entered:" immediately underneath it updates and displays, `You entered: Goodbye` when I finish typing.

```
| Unique Name | Freeform                                       |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| ABC         | (Editable input box displaying "Hello World!") |
|             | You entered: Hello World!                      |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| JKL         | (Editable input box displaying "Goodbye")      |
|             | You entered: Goodbye                           |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| XYZ         | (Editable input box displaying "Hello World!") |
|             | You entered: Hello World!                      |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
```

I read https://lwc.dev/guide/html_templates#handle-user-input, but it seems to presume that there's a globally scoped variable used as the `value` for your `<lightning-input>` *(e.g. in `this.name = event.target.value;`)*.

My `<lightning-input>`'s value, however, is a temporary loop reference to a piece of an array variable *(`{w_record.value_for_freeform_column}`)*.

**Is there some sort of code I could write that would let me write a `handleInput(event)`-like JavaScript controller function capable of assigning `event.target.value` to such a locally-scoped-in-the-HTML variable?**

*(Note:  I'll want any edits to a property of `w_record` to either update the corresponding piece of `wrapped_records` or to be easy to fetch later, since in the bigger picture, my HTML table is a way of rendering a complex data entry form whose final values will need to be sent back to Apex as part of some complex DML operations when the user clicks "all done.")*

Comment: Can you add playground link as well?https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by sfdcfox you can use, data attributes,

if you dont wanna use data attribute you can use `lightning-input` `name` attribute instead.

```
<template for:each={wrapped_records} for:item="w_record">
                    <tr key={w_record.unique_name}>
                        <th data-label="UniqueName" scope="row" key={w_record.unique_name}>
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={w_record.unique_name}><b><u>{w_record.unique_name}</u></b></div>
                        </th>
                        <td data-label="Freeform" title={w_record.unique_name} key={w_record.unique_name}>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">
                                <lightning-input name={w_record.unique_name}
                                    type="text" 
                                    label="Need to enter a manual value?" 
                                    variant="label-hidden" onchange={updateFreeFormColum}
                                    value={w_record.value_for_freeform_column}
                                    placeholder="type here..."
                                >
                                </lightning-input>
                                You entered:  <em>{w_record.value_for_freeform_column}</em>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track wrapped_records = [{unique_name:'ABC' , value_for_freeform_column : 'Hello World'} ,
     {unique_name:'JKL' ,value_for_freeform_column : 'Hello World'}  , 
     {unique_name:'XYZ' , value_for_freeform_column : 'Hello World'}];

     updateFreeFormColum(event){
        console.log(event.target.name);

        var foundElement = this.wrapped_records.find(function(element){
            return element.unique_name === event.target.name;
        });        
        foundElement.value_for_freeform_column = event.target.value;

     }
}
```

Playground Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/K88RmBKA6/1/edit

Comment: Thanks -- followup question.  Is accessing the equivalent of `element.unique_name` inside the `.find()` function going to need to be different when `wrapped_records` comes out of the `result` of an Apex returning a `List<SomeObject>` than when it's written as a JSON literal like in your example?  The code works, then `element.unique_name` goes undefined if I try to wire back in the Apex.  It looks like it's buried deep in some sort of `Proxy` and `originalTarget` structure?

Comment: its a proxy right, used for caching, if you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.wrapped_records));` you will see your records in JSON format

Comment: My errors flipping between the literal-defined `wrapped_records` and the Apex-populated version ended up being some unrelated typos ... thanks for the `stringify()` tip!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fvY678I6Y/1/edit) that demonstrates how to set an onchange handler like what you're asking for:

---

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track rows;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.rows = [{id:0,value:''},{id:1,value:''},{id:2,value:''}];
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.rows[event.target.closest('[data-key]').dataset.key].value = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <template for:each={rows} for:item="item">
        <div key={item.id} data-key={item.id}>
            <input onchange={handleChange} value={item.value} /><br />
            "{item.value}"
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

---

Basically, we assign the key to an item we can inspect (data-key), then use that to update the array in the controller.

Comment: What's the `connectedCallback()` for, and what exactly are you setting with `0`, `1`, and `2`?

Comment: @k.. `connectedCallback` is a special method that is called when a component is loaded. The values 0, 1, and 2 are just index values in to the array. You could do it other ways, too, like by a record Id, then you'd need to use Array.prototype.find instead. This is just a simple self-contained example.

Comment: I got Pranay's variation working a little faster than this one made sense to me at my skill level for JavaScript, so I accepted that one, but I appreciate you being so fast on the ball -- also great information to know, thanks!