# Open a custom object from a click on the LWC page

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to open a custom object from a click on the LWC page.

Using the html below I get the expected icon and can click on it getting the console.log() in the js below. And if I hardcode the RecordId in the js it opens that record.

**Specific description of the problem:**
I do not get the recordId dynamically from that click.  What am I missing?

**No Error messages.**

```
<template for:each={registrations.data} for:item="record">
<lightning-layout-item key={record.Id} size="4" class="slds-p-around_x-small">
    <lightning-card title={record.Name__c} class="registration-tile">

        <div slot="actions">
            <lightning-button-icon
                icon-name="utility:search"
                icon-class="registration-button"
                variant="bare"
                alternative-text="Open record"
                onclick={handleOpenRecordClick}>
            </lightning-button-icon>
        </div>
```

js
Hardcoded RecordID works but I'm not getting the dynamic record ID

```
handleOpenRecordClick (event) {
    console.log("Click Open ");
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: 'a03S0000006rKe6IAE' , // HARDCODED Works but event.target.registration.Id, no data
            objectApiName: 'lutd_Registration__c',
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: You can refer example give here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284842/lwc-inside-an-html-template-for-loop-set-loop-variable-property-to-new-user-ty

Comment: Cool link I may need that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the value attribute in `lightning button icon`  tag . 
Refer the below code for your reference

HTML -

```
<template for:each={registrations.data} for:item="record">
<lightning-layout-item key={record.Id} size="4" class="slds-p-around_x-small">
    <lightning-card title={record.Name__c} class="registration-tile">

        <div slot="actions">
            <lightning-button-icon
                icon-name="utility:search"
                value={record.Id}
                icon-class="registration-button"
                variant="bare"
                alternative-text="Open record"
                onclick={handleOpenRecordClick}>
            </lightning-button-icon>
        </div>
```

And get the record value by `event.target.value` in JS code.

Please let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thanks for the fast and precise answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks Dan :) you can upvote my answer too